# What does this yum error mean?

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

I don't understand the phrasing of this error message.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
 Error: Package: kf5-kactivities-libs-devel-4.100.0-1.fc20.x86_64 (dvratil-kde-frameworks)
            Requires: kf5-kactivities-libs(x86-64) = 4.100.0-1.fc20
            Available: kf5-kactivities-libs-4.100.0-1.fc20.x86_64 (dvratil-kde-frameworks)
                kf5-kactivities-libs(x86-64) = 4.100.0-1.fc20
            Installing: kf5-kactivities-libs-5.0.0-1.fc20.x86_64 (dvratil-kde-frameworks)
                kf5-kactivities-libs(x86-64) = 5.0.0-1.fc20
  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

This is caused by a missing dependency, right? However it doesn't say it failed at any point in the error message. The way I read it, yum is saying "I know what package version you need. I successfully found it, are you sure you want this one? Nope, I'll install a later version I found. By the way, here's how to work around the problem I never explained".

Am I misunderstanding something? Is this package available or not?

Comment: What was the command that resulted in this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid guessing, you have to put the full command that you are issuing.

But I think that `yum` says that `kf5-kactivities-libs-devel` version `4.100.0-1` needs, as dependency, the package `kf5-kactivities-libs` version `4.100.0-1`, but you are installing version `5.0.0-1` of `kf5-kactivities-libs`.

HTH,

Germán.